# Как сделать это бесконечным?

Tags: python

```
import time
from pyrogram import Client
api_id = 149
api_hash = "6a0158a6d4d"
with Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash) as app: 
    time = time.time()
    newtime = time + 3600   
    suka = app.get_history(-1001397278473, limit=1)
    mid = suka[0].message_id
    if mid >= 3:
        app.forward_messages(-1001167309171, "-1001397278473", mid, as_copy=True, remove_caption=True,schedule_date=int(newtime))
        app.delete_messages(-1001397278473, int(mid))
        newtime + 3600
    else:
        print("404")
```

Comment: `while True: ...` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while True:
    with Client("my_account", api_id, api_hash) as app: 
        time = time.time()
        newtime = time + 3600   
        suka = app.get_history(-1001397278473, limit=1)
        mid = suka[0].message_id
        if mid >= 3:
            app.forward_messages(-1001167309171, "-1001397278473", mid, as_copy=True, remove_caption=True,schedule_date=int(newtime))
            app.delete_messages(-1001397278473, int(mid))
            newtime + 3600
        else:
            print("404")
```